# How does "configure" script detect if my system support some header files or cpp feature?

Tags: c++, header, include, configure, automake

I'm trying to compile google rpc(grpc) on my RHEL 5 box, the configure script checks and throws this error:

```
configure: error: sched_yield was not found on your system
```

I checked config.log file and found sth like this:

```
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char sched_yield ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return sched_yield ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:19729: result: no
configure:19736: error: in `/downloads/grpc/third_party/protobuf':
configure:19738: error: sched_yield was not found on your system
```

Well, it's correct, I did a manual test and  is not found. No problem.

```
But, I just wish to know the principle behind "configure"!
```

Does "configure" try to generate some c/c++ source code and compile it, in order to see if some features are supported? As you know the "configure" script usually run very fast, much faster than calling a lot of gcc/g++ processes to try headers/features.

So how does "configure" achieve this header/feature "check"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does "configure" try to generate some c/c++ source code and compile it, in order to see if some features are supported?

Yes.

> As you know the "configure" script usually run very fast [...]

Not in my experience. `configure` is slowwwwww...

> So how does "configure" achieve this header/feature "check"?

See Q #1.

Comment: Agreed, configure is slow enough that you don't want to run it every day. I just wish recursive project configure could reuse the answers!